# Fallout 4 quests with workbench tasks

Tags: fallout-4

I've got 2 quests now ("A New Threat", where you have to build a robot workbench) and "The Molecular Level", where you have to build a bunch of things and hook them together) that have the same issue in common.
When I go to a workbench and build these items, nothing happens.
The quest is not progressed in any way and when I look at the quest tasks, there's no indication that I've completed the build task.
I can build just fine....the items are placed and even in the case of the robot workbench, it functions.  It just doesn't allow me to install ADA's radar beacon since I never get to "talk to ADA" and move onto the next task, since I'm stuck on the build task.
My installation is modded, however I've gone and removed any mods I can see that are related to companions and/or settlements....but no effect.
I've confirmed (on the NMM plugins tab) there are no load order conflicts.
And in the case of the "A New Threat" quest, I've tried the "setstage DLC01MQ02 XXXX" approach, which causes the icon above ADA's head to appear, but still no progress in the quest takes place.
In my research of this, I've been seeing folks with both modded and non-modded installs having these issues as well as console users experiencing the same issue.
Question: Does anyone have a solution for this, or is this just a plain old bug that I need to wait for 1.5 to resolve?
I'll try participating in the 1.5.151 Beta for now, just to see if that fixes it, but I just wanted to know if I should sit back and wait for Bethesda to fix this or if there are other workarounds I should try.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you listen to the distress signal once and also visited Wattz Consumer Electronics?

Comment: Can you list the exact objective currently listed for both quests?

Comment: Baumi: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've listened to all of the distress signals I've encountered.  I've not visited Wattz Consumer Electronics.  Is that related?

Comment: DCShannon: On "The Molecular Level", the object is "Build the Reflector Platform".  I can build it, but there's no indication that the objective is then complete.  Similar to "A New Threat" where the objective is "Build a Robot Workbench".  I can build it, and it even works where I can build a robot if I want.  But the objective doesn't complete and when I use the robot workbench on ADA, there's no option for anything to do with a Radar Beacon (because I can't get to the "Speak to ADA" quest since the "Build a Robot Workbench" objective never completes.  Need to know my mods?

Comment: BTW - I temporarily tried the 1.5 beta, but couldn't get it to work (CTD on game load), so I backed that off.  Back to 1.4.132.0.0 with script extender v0.1.8.

Comment: Mods: 
Pip-Boy Flashlight, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10840; 
Armor and Weapon Keywords Community Resource (AWKCR), http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6091; 
High Resolution Texture Pack - Valius - 2k and 4k, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/318; 
Place Everywhere, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/9424; 
Vanilla Extensions, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10032; 
Better Armor Mod Descriptions, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5028; 
Valdacil's Item Sorting, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/3877

Comment: Crafting Workbenches ((INACTIVE)), http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2451; 
Where Are You Now - Companion Tracking, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/7903; 
Zoom-Out Extended for World Map and Local Map - For 2K 4K 8K WorldMaps, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/9144; 
DEF_UI, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10654; 
Fallout 4 HD Reworked Project, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10467; 
Snapable Junk Fences, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/9000; 
Vivid Fallout - Landscapes, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/1769

Comment: Spring Cleaning, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4640; 
Enhanced Wasteland Preset, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/40; 
Satellite World Map, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/8989; 
Settlement Keywords (SK) ((INACTIVE)), http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/7259; 
Alternate Settlements ((INACTIVE)), http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5118; 
True Storms: Wasteland Edition, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4472; 
Craftable Ramps and Rails, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6155

Comment: Clean Power Armor HUD, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/178; 
Fallout 4 Enhanced Color Correction, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5060; 
Simple Intersection, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2683; 
Lowered Weapons, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/522; 
Value per Weight indicator for container UI, http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/334

Comment: Have you wired up all the parts of the teleporter? You have to build the platform first, then build the emitter on top of it. Then build the dish and the console somewhere near and wire it all up. Finally you have to supply it with enough energy (27).

Comment: Bounce: Using workbenches, I only see the Reflector Platform and Robot Workbench as options.  No other items appear as anything I can build.  When I do build either of these, nothing happens to advanced my quest tasks, so I assume(?), if I were to advanced onto other tasks, I would be able to build those other items(?).  But currently, only the reflector platform and robot workbench appear.  I've watched videos on how to complete the quests.  It's just that anything related to building via a workbench does NOT progress me in any way in my quest task list.

Comment: It has to be a bug of some kind.  I completely removed ALL of my mods and went back to try these quests, but same result.  I can built stuff, but the quest does not progress...the "Build...." task remains un-completed so I can't move forward any.  I have 1.5.157 now, since it was just released, but apparently these bugs weren't addressed in that patch.